# Discord bot copy and paste

Tags: python, discord

So currently I'm trying to make a bot that will copy a portion of my message, and use it in the bot's message.

My code so far is

```
if message.content.startswith("insult"):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(insult))
```

I'm trying to make it do something like, for example, "insult jerry", the bot would copy and say Jerry's name from my message and then choose one of the insults from the list I already made.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def insult(ctx, name : str):
    await ctx.send(f'{name} {random.choice(insult)}')
```